# BGStretcher Jquery Plugin IE 8 and 7 issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, cross-browser

I'm using BGStretcher plugin and having a bit of problem make it work in IE8 and 7 it works fine in all the other browsers i was just wondering if someone came across the same problem image just will not show in those two Browsers here is url: http://www.bonta.co.uk/
Many thanks,

Comment: I am a great believer that we should shun all browsers made by Microsoft. We have suffered through 15 years of bad browsers. To their credit IE9 seems to be better.

Comment: By the way your site shows find in firefox and chrome

Comment: yeah Chrome and FF are fine its only useless IE8 which is quite popular among people. I find IE9 as bad as other IE versions :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the plugin, but I know that http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image has really good info on full page backgrounds, they list quite a few solutions.

Comment: Thanks Joseph i will have a proper look but i think none of those solutions offers background scrolling effect which i would like to achieve

Comment: If you mean you wish to have the background fixed while the rest of the site scrolls, then yes, most of those solutions acheive that.
Best of Luck!